# Solace Appliance 3560 - Input Stream Vs RAM - Not Requested vs Synchronized

Tags: solace, solace-mq

What is difference of Deliver from, Input Stream Vs RAM on Solace Appliance under Queue Client Flow Information ?

What is difference between Status Update, Not Requested vs Synchronized on Solace Appliance under Queue Client Flow Information ?

Answer (score 2):

When Guaranteed messages are being delivered to the client immediately after being spooled, the egress flow is in the delivered from ‘input stream’ state. If the client cannot receive the message right away, the guaranteed messages are delivered once the client is ready, thus requiring further processing. The egress flow shows either delivered from ‘RAM’ or ‘ADB or disk’ in this case.

The Status Updates field indicates whether a client is up to date with the state of the flow if the client has requested 'Active Flow Indication'. A value of "Not Requested" means that the 'Active Flow Indication' property is disabled for that particular flow. A value of "Synchronized" means that the client has the 'Active Flow Indication' property enabled and the client is up-to-date with the state of the flow.